Receiving CORS Error in Browser and 500 Internal Server Error Through API When Website Was Previously Working
I was looking into the network calls made by a website (not mine) to understand how the website works. Each time I would reload the page, I would look at the network calls being made in the developer tools of Chrome. Then, I would sift through the calls, find the one I wanted, and see what parameters it took, etc. I then recreated the call in Postman to get the syntax down and find all the necessary parameters before finally coding it into a little bot I'm making as a side project. I was doing this over and over with no problem until suddenly, I started getting a 500 Internal Server Error on the second call. I haven't changed anything in my code or in Postman, but both are now returning a 500 error when previously they were successful. These are simple GET requests with just a couple parameters. The first API call in the process goes through fine, but the second one returns a 500 error. When I checked online as well, I am seeing that the first call is being made on the corresponding page, but when I navigate to the next page for the second call, it is stuck loading. When looking at the console in the developer tools, it is complaining about a CORS Error. Now, even if I go on my phone and check, the same thing is happening, but if I disconnect from wifi the page loads fine. What happened? How do I fix it?
I've tried hitting the API in different ways (Browser, Postman, Custom Java Program). I've also tried using an incognito tab, restarting chrome, restarting my computer, restarting my internet, and waiting a day. I've attempted to research workarounds but they all have to do with locally owned servers, and I can't find a solution for a website that is not personally owned by the user and one that should be working. Also, I've tried using the Allow CORS extension and even that didn't work.
EDIT:
It looks like when a server returns a 500 Internal Server Error it leaves out the CORS header necessary to prevent the CORS Error. So that explains why I'm seeing a CORS Error in the browser, but why would I suddenly get a 500 Error for this API when I wasn't before, AND when I don't get any error not on my internet. Did it somehow flag my IP or something for calling their APIs incorrectly?

As you already guessed, it is very likely, that you were blacklisted. Depending on the frequency of your bot's requests, you should consider the legality of your project. Sites that are victim to such bots often introduce a request-counter that blocks an ip if too many requests are made in a certain timeframe. To solve this, you should contact the website's owner and ask which ways he would allow to access the data you require.
